# Shell Script to read the file and find the highest count

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting.I need to write a script to read each line from the file. Let's say each line has ID like A, B, C, D etc. But there can be duplicate IDs also. Two  or more lines can have same ID. I need to find out the highest number for each ID. i.e if there are 3 IDs as "A". then I need to find out which is highest among those 3. and so on for ID "B", "C",,,and so on....

Thank you...

Comment: two questions 1) Is this homework? 2) can you please provide an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: Please be more clear.. Can you provide some sample file that you are looking at?

Answer (score 1):

#### Sample data:

```
A 3
B 2
C 4
A 1
B 9
A 6
```

#### Run command:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr data.txt | sort -u -k1,1
```

#### Output:

```
A 6
B 9
C 4
```